# Insert row into database table using NHibernate without calling scope_identity after the row has been inserted

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to insert a large volume of data with NHibernate into a database, and it's very slow in doing so.  I've read around it and the suggestion everywhere is to let NH set the identity of the row so that it can batch and not need to call SCOPE_IDENTITY after the insert, however, it's a brownfield app with a legacy database, so I can't let NHibernate control the identity of the rows.

Is there any way I can tell NH to just not select scope identity and to just insert the rows into the database?  I don't need it to know about their identity at this time, so it makes little difference whether or not the rows know their identity after the insert, but I'm guessing I can't just tell Nhibernate not to retrieve the identity in this case?

Using Fluent NH if that's of any consequence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that really an issue? SCOPE_IDENTITY should be a session property with no need to do any database operation such as writing data and updating table indexes - it might need an extra round-trip to the database but that's it and it should be relatively cheap compared to all your other operations. Why would that make a noticeable difference slowing down inserts?

Comment: @rup Yes it's very relevant. db generated keys prevent nhibernate from using batching features. In the end it is not the scope_identity as such that is the problem but that scope_identity is required after each individual insert making bulk inserts unacceptable slow

Comment: @Eddy that's basically it yeah.  This was a final desperate attempt to bend NHibernate before just setting it up as a SQL command.

Comment: @Eddy "db generated keys prevent nhibernate from using batching features." But you can return all the IDs in one go from a multiple insert can't you? e.g. `insert into person(name) output inserted.id values('Alice'),('Bob'),('Charlie');`

Comment: What is your target database? Do you use something like Repository<T> which manages sessions and connections for your mapping types? If mssql and yes: I added a BulkInsert to my repository which creates a datatable based on the mapping type's properties, copy in the rows and use SqlBulkCopy to do the insert. It ain't perfect but it's lightning fast.

Comment: @Eddy Yeah it's MSSQL 2008 - I'm looking at SqlBulkCopy at the moment, there's various Enumerable-to-Datareader implemntations about that I'm looking at at the moment.  Any tips on the best way to do it?

Comment: @Eddy how did you get round getting hold of the column names of any properties with a foreign key relationship?  Or did you not need to?  I've got properties where the names don't match columns and though I can get them to map up, the relationship columns are causing me nightmares!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NH requires the identity to manage the entities in the cache to identify them. So I don't think that there is a way around.

You performance problems don't necessarily be caused by the identity. It may be that you flush the session too many times. Try turning off auto flush to verify it or use a StatelessSession.

An ORM is not very good in large mass operations. You should consider to use something more low-level (like SQL).

Comment: I'm using a stateless session which is being created and disposed for just this one query, and trying to insert 20K+ records into the database.  Because the identity is being generated by the database, there's no batching happening on the query, so I get 20K+ individual insert and scope identity statements, which means the insert is inordinately slow.  I know it's going against all principles of NH, but as I have to try to use it, I was wondering whether anyone knew of some witchcraft I could employ.  I realise it was a long shot.